# Notification removed to left or right

Tags: android

I'm programming an android app, which shows a notification. I know how to show it but how can my app learn whether it is removed by being swiped right or left? Is there any way to know this?

This is the way I created the notification:

```
public void showNotification(){
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("My notification");
    mBuilder.setContentText("Hello World!");
    Notification mNotification = mBuilder.build();
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(R.id.note, mNotification);
}
```

Comment: I think it's just "swipe to dismiss". If you want different actions, you add buttons like Gmail archive or reply, for  example

Comment: no. there's no way to know that. Whatever you're planning with this action you'll have to do it differently.